# jquery array[index] returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, undefined

Trying to call .fadeOut() on an array of `<li>`'s using an index returns the dom Element and not a jQuery object. I've stumble on this issue once before but can't seem to remember why this happens, any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentSlide = 0,
        slides       = $('#homeSlider ul li'),
        slideLength  = slides.length;

    var slideInterval = setInterval(function(){

        if(currentSlide >= slideLength-1) {
            currentSlide = 0;
        } else {
            currentSlide++; 
        }

        slides[currentSlide].fadeOut(); /* <-- undefined is not a function */

    }, 2000); // end slide setInterval


});// end doc ready
```

Comment: might be that you reach index that is out of the `slides` bounds.

Comment: A console.log(slides[currentSlide]); returns the <li>'s with the correct index and loops with the if/else. I just can't seem to call a jQuery method on these elements.

Comment: Because it's a DOM node, you identify that *in your question*. Why would you think that DOM nodes would have access to a jQuery method, from a library..?

Comment: To my understanding, defining the slides variable using a jQuery selector $('') extends the library to these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a jQuery method, a function of a jQuery object, on a DOM node. Predictably this won't, and *can't* work. To make use of jQuery methods in this situation you can either re-wrap the DOM node:

```
$(slides[currentSlide]).fadeOut();
```

Or use `eq()`, to effectively trim the jQuery object down to only that (still-wrapped) node at the supplied index:

```
slides.eq(currentSlide).fadeOut();
```

The reason that using `slides[currentSlide]` returns a DOM node is because jQuery masquerades as an array, supplying a numeric index therefore returns the element stored at that index.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. I like the eq method, I'll be sure to use that more in the future.